# Chrome Extension JQuery not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that changes every image on any website when the user clicks a button but the JQuery file is not loading.

```js
$("#change").click(function(){
     $("img").attr("src", "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg");
});
```

```css
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Getting started example",
"description": "example",
"version": "1.0",

"content_scripts": [{
"js": ["changeIMG.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"],
"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab"
]


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="change">Click</button>

<script src="changeIMG.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Swap the script orders in the manifest file "js" property.  You're loading your script before jQuery, and since your script requires jQuery it's failing.

Comment: In addition to @Archer's suggestion also check the console to see if there any error message that can tell you what else you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Only locally included files can be declared in `content_scripts` section.